# Receive data from serialport in realtime VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, synchronization, real-time

I created this code to receive data from serial port (com)

```
 Private port As New SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)

Function ReceiveSerialData() As String

    Dim returnStr As String = ""

    Dim com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    Try

        port.Open()

        port.ReadTimeout = 1000

        Dim Incoming As String

            Incoming = port.ReadLine()

        returnStr = Incoming

    Catch erreur As IOException
        returnStr = "Check Port"
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If port IsNot Nothing Then port.Close()
    End Try

    Return returnStr
End Function



Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

    Label2.Content = ReceiveSerialData()

End Sub
```

I want to create an event to re execute this code when the data's changed in real time.

My Form is like this : 
[image]

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You could add a handler to the [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Comment: if you put the read code in a while loop, it will do as you require.

Comment: @Jaxi I tried to put while loop   but it's not working

Comment: @soohoonigan how to use it ( and thanks )

Comment: That depends on how your device is set up to communicate. If it's constantly sending data back, then just add a handler to that event I linked. If the device needs to be queried before it sends data back, then use a timer and continually request data from it

Comment: Does your code work the first time? I mean, is it getting the data from the Scale when you call `ReceiveSerialData()`? (I assume it is a Scale).

Comment: @kalanag yes it's work when i execute it, just i need to get data instantaneous the data came from a balance

Comment: so for example `While True Label2.Content = ReceiveSerialData() End While` does not work? while true is never recommended, but this is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always go with some form of the Do While True mentioned in the comments. Not ideal but...

This is a modified version of your code, to include the reading part in a different thread. When it reads something, it raises an event you can subscribe to (or you could simply put the text in your control directly after reading). The port stays open all the time, so in this example it is being closed when the form is closed.

Try it and see if it works for you.

```
Private port As New SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
Private rdthread As System.Threading.Thread
Event PortData(ByVal Message as String)

Private Sub readPort()
    Do While True
        Try
            Dim message As String = port.ReadLine()
            RaiseEvent PortData(message)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
            My.Application.DoEvents()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Do
        End Try
    Loop
End Sub    

Private Sub HandleData(ByVal message as string) Handles Me.PortData
    Label2.Content = message
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    InitPort()
End Sub

Private Sub Window_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Try
        If port.IsOpen Then port.Close()
    Finally
        port.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub 

Sub InitPort() 
    Dim com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    Try
        port.Open()
        port.ReadTimeout = 1000

        rdthread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf readPort)
        rdthread.Start()

    Catch erreur As IOException
        returnStr = "Check Port"
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Catch ex as Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```