# multi-thread timing adjustment

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

In VB.net, I use loops for multi-threaded timing adjustment (when I cannot predict when an event will occur in this other thread). The other thread waits the response from a device which is connected
through serial port. Once data is available, this lets me know about the results by using `Invoke` and `Delegate`. The main part of the codes is something like below.

```
data = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
Invoke( New Delegate_RcvDataToTextBox( AddressOf Me.RcvDataToTextBox ), args )
```

On the other hand, the main thread waits and polls the other thread by using a do-loop.
This loop consists of a `do` loop, `DoEvents()` and a `if` statement. I would like to avoid such kind of
combination, i.e., `do`-loop and `DoEvents`. What kind of learning should I do for that?

```
do 
 system.....DoEvents()
 if data.isnothing = false then...
loop while (1)
```

Comment: So you are trying to read from a serial port? Is that the actual problem?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881904/receive-data-from-serialport-in-realtime-vb-net help? Have you read up on the `DataReceived` event?

Comment: It sounds like you may be doing a lot of useless work. You should likely just be handling the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event. The handler for that event is already raised on a secondary thread. There's no need for you to create a second thread yourself and no need for a useless busy-wait loop on the UI thread.

Comment: Why are you trying to block the thread? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Notwithstanding the more specific suggestions on working with the serial port, a more general solution to your problem is one of the concurrent collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent`, which support a blocking wait for a new item to be added.

Comment: Thanks for comments. By referring past StackOverFlow thread introduced by mjwills, I changed my code despite still using do-doevent-loop.